# how to use collide direct for multiple sprites

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

```
#sprites

import random, sys, time, math, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library

FPS = 30 # frames per second to update the screen
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
WINWIDTH = 1500 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINHEIGHT = 1000 # height in pixels
HALF_WINWIDTH = int(WINWIDTH / 2)
HALF_WINHEIGHT = int(WINHEIGHT / 2)


moveX,moveY=0,0
move2X,move2Y=0,0


GRASSCOLOR = (24, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.init()


global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, self
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('god.png'))
pygame.display.set_caption('Smash Bros Melee')
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=50
        self.height=50
        self.i0= pygame.image.load('ryanrenolds.jpeg')

        self.timeTarget=10
        self.timeNum=0
        self.currentImage=0

    def render(self):

            DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.i0, (self.x, self.y))

player=Sprite(0,0)

class Sprite2:
    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=50
        self.height=50
        self.i0= pygame.image.load('ArkhamKnight.png')
        self.i1= pygame.image.load('Black-Panther.png')
        self.timeTarget=10
        self.timeNum=0
        self.currentImage=0

    def update(self):

        self.timeNum+=1

        if (self.timeNum==self.timeTarget):

            if (self.currentImage==0):
                self.currentImage+=1
            else:
                self.currentImage=0
            self.timeNum=0
        self.render()

    def render(self):

        if(self.currentImage==0):
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.i0, (self.x, self.y))

        else:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.i1, (self.x, self.y))

player2=Sprite2(200,300)

def checkCollision(Sprite, Sprite2):
  col = Sprite.rect.colliderect(Sprite2.rect)
  if col == True:
    sys.exit()


while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():


                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == K_a:
                       moveX = moveX - 0
                    elif event.key == K_d:
                       moveX == False
                    elif event.key == K_w:
                       moveY == False
                    elif event.key == K_s:
                       moveY == False

                if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                   if (event.key==pygame.K_a):
                      moveX = moveX - 5
                   elif (event.key==pygame.K_d):
                       moveX = moveX + 5
                   elif (event.key==pygame.K_w):
                       moveY = moveY - 5
                   elif (event.key==pygame.K_s):
                       moveY = moveY + 5
                   elif (event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                       pygame.quit()
                       sys.exit()


                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == K_LEFT:
                       move2X = move2X - 0
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        move2X == False
                    elif event.key == K_UP:
                        move2Y == False
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        move2Y == False

                if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):
                        move2X = move2X - 5
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):
                        move2X = move2X + 5
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_UP):
                        move2Y = move2Y - 5
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):
                        move2Y = move2Y + 5
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_o):
                        player=Sprite(0,0)
                        player2=Sprite2(200,300)
                    elif (event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

         DISPLAYSURF.fill(PURPLE)
         player.x+=moveX
         player.y+=moveY
         player2.x+=move2X
         player2.y+=move2Y
         player.render()
         player2.update()
         checkCollision(Sprite, Sprite2)
         pygame.display.update()
         fpsClock.tick(FPS)

 pygame.quit()
 sys.exit()
```

how do i get to wear my sprites will collide my collide direct code asks for three arguements when i used self in the parameters but when i took self out it says that class Sprite has no attribute 'rect'

This the error i keep getting how do i fix this to where my game works to where my sprites will exit the game if they collide with each other

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sprites\sprites.py", line 159, in 
    checkCollision(Sprite, Sprite2)
  File "C:\Python27\Sprites\sprites.py", line 88, in checkCollision
    col = Sprite.rect.colliderect(Sprite2.rect)
AttributeError: class Sprite has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the code...

Comment: yes were do you need the indention to be fixed

Comment: But that error *tells you* what the problem is! Look at your (?) definition of `Sprite2`. Does it define a member `rect`? No. So add it (if you think you need it) or change the code in the line that uses it.

Comment: So do i need to initialize rect equals self.x, slef.y? for both of my sprites @usr2564301

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the attribute `rect` in your Sprite class, which is causing this problem. You also need an attribute `rect` in your Sprite2 class. You can do this by using the `get_rect()` method.

You can do this in your Sprite class by entering this in the `__init__(self)`

```
self.rect = self.i0.get_rect()
```

And for the Sprite2 class you can do this (because displayed image can change, put this in the `update()`.)

```
if self.currentImage == 0:
    self.rect = self.i0.get_rect()
elif self.currentImage == 1:
    self.rect = self.i1.get_rect()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hey @Ethanol i had used your get_rect() code and it gave me a new error ill share you my code and show you my new error